# php apache permissions - best practices

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application which creates folders using php. The owner of any folders created via php is 'apache', however if I want to upload a folder via ftp the owner is my ftp username.

I had an issue with php (apache) not being able to modify a file inside a folder that was uploaded via ftp because of permissions. In the meantime I have added my ftpuser to the apache group and apache to the ftpuser group but was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I recommend read this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/357109/233024

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally what I do is chgrp any directory php will write to the group apache runs as (www on my server, could be apache on yours), chmod g+s . This will make any file created in that directory also owned by the web server group.  If the default umask allows group write, this will solve your problem.

Comment: So just to clarify, if I chmod g+s on the whole website directory and use www-data but then ftp via my ftp user and upload files, all uploaded files will automatically be owned by www-data?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to only allow users to read/write files that they should.

In my web-apps, I have a data directory for the website, which I store all my dynamically generated data from the app.

Then I only give permission for the app to write to that directory, and nothing else.